# How do start using the deployed wirecloud in the lab?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have just deployed an image of wirecloud on the https://cloud.lab.fiware.org/#nova/images/

I gave it a floating ip and then I connected to it via ssh.

**Now what?**

I cant find any command to issue in order to start using wirecloud, the entire user guide ([https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-*Wirecloud*-_User_and_Programmer_Guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide)) is about the UI.

I tried going to the assigned floating ip but all I get is the page (http://150.254.155.20/) from which I cannot log in.

**So how do I set up and use the wirecloud once I ssh'ed my way inside the apparently ubuntu machine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WireCloud Image available on FIWARE Lab deploys a WireCloud instance at `/opt/wirecloud_instance`. This instance configures a default admin user (credentials: admin/admin). The first step is to modify this admin user, to do so you have to login inside WireCloud and entering the Django admin panel:

[image]

Once in the admin panel, open "Auth -> Users -> admin" and update your admin user:

[image]

You can also change the default configuration of this instance (for example, change the default theme, add the emails for error reporting, etc...), please take a look into the [Installation and Administration guide for more info](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Extra_options).

P.D. Currently the WireCloud image uses WireCloud `0.6.2`. You can update it using the following commands:

```
$ pip install -U wirecloud
$ cd /opt/wirecloud_instance
$ python manage.py syncdb --migrate; python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python manage.py compress --force
```

Comment: That was helpful. Can you tell me now, since I am making an android application that has its own mysql database in my server, how can I map the user of wirecloud with the user of my own database?

The point of this is to recognize which user is consuming the widget

Comment: That's another question, please create it and I will answer your :)